# Accessing style items by style ID

Tags: android

Any View have a constructor 
`public View (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)` which is
called when `View` declared with a style attribute. 
So, if I have some class inherited from `View` class, I can access 
declared attributes (like `android:layout_width` or 
`android:background`) via `AttributeSet` attrs in a constructor. But 
when I move attributes to style I cannot see attributes and values 
exists in a style. I want to read items declared in style but I have 
only style ID in `defStyle` parameter. Is there some way to read style 
items using the style ID?

Answer (score 0):

changing the style after creating the view is not supported .. so what you can do is :

1 - create a new android xml file of type values
2 - add new theme
3 - add your elements to that theme and their values and save the file

now when you are dynamically creating the new view you call the constructor that will allow to define a defStyle .. then you point to the style ID you have just created by pointing to R."the XML file name"."your style ID"